# How to declare a value in a variable where string and char both are present

Tags: php

Suppose i have to declare an integer value, than i can do it easily do it like

```
$myId = 1001;
```

same against the char as well

```
$myId = mprGRqw;
```

But how can i declare a value where the string and char both are present like ---

```
1001sd467WprfFE
```

I canot declare it like

```
$myId= 1001sd467WprfFE;
```

I have search a lot, but i did not find any good solution to solve this problem, any one have any idea how to declare a value where the string and char both are present.

I am working on php.

Comment: What is wrong with `$myId= '1001sd467WprfFE';` unless you are not comparing with `==`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure how `$myId = mprGRqw;` would be considered valid in a default PHP environment.
In general, all strings should be enclosed with single or double quotes, like:

```
$myId = "1001sd467WprfFE";
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap the values in quotes:

```
$myId= "1001sd467WprfFE";
```

Additionally I would suggest you to go through with [PHP Mannual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the variable if its sting then use quotes like

```
$myId= '1001sd467WprfFE';
```

OR

```
$myId= "1001sd467WprfFE";
```

It its a numeric value at the time you should use like this

```
$myId= 1001;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are declare `$myId = mprGRqw;` like this this is not valid way. If `mprGRqw` is defined constant then it is possible to use like this. If you want to declare variable `$myId` as `varchar`, you can try this:

```
$myId= "1001sd467WprfFE";
```

Or

```
$myId= '1001sd467WprfFE';
```